How do build a user follower/following model using async SQLModel / FastAPI
I have the following code:
# models.py

class UserFollowLink(SQLModel, table=True):
    follower_id: int = Field(default=None, foreign_key="users.id", primary_key=True)
    followed_id: int = Field(default=None, foreign_key="users.id", primary_key=True)

class User(SQLModel, table=True)
    following: list["User"] = Relationship(
        back_populates="followers",
        link_model=UserFollowLink,
        sa_relationship_kwargs={
            "lazy": "selectin",
            "foreign_keys": "[UserFollowLink.follower_id]",
        },
    )
    followers: list["User"] = Relationship(
        back_populates="following",
        link_model=UserFollowLink,
        sa_relationship_kwargs={
            "lazy": "selectin",
            "foreign_keys": "[UserFollowLink.followed_id]",
        },
    )

# routes.py

from .deps import DB, CurrentUser
...
@router.get("/{user_id}/follow")
async def follow_user(db: DB, current_user: CurrentUser, user_id: int):
    user = await db.get(User, user_id)
    if not user:
        raise HTTPException(status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND, "User not found")
    current_user.following.append(user) # <--- breaking point
    db.add(current_user)
    await db.commit()
    return current_user

Line current_user.following.append(user) is where I always get the MissingGreenlet error below. I tried to play around with different lazy configurations but nothing I tried works. I feel like there is some kind of additional sa_relationship_kwargs I need to add to make this work, but not sure which.
sqlalchemy.exc.MissingGreenlet: greenlet_spawn has not been called; can't call await_only() here. Was IO attempted in an unexpected place?

And here is the DB dependency incase that helps.
# deps.py
...
async_engine = create_async_engine(settings.SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI, echo=False)

async_session = async_sessionmaker(
    async_engine, class_=AsyncSession, expire_on_commit=False
)

async def get_db() -> AsyncIterator[AsyncSession]:
    async with async_session() as session:
        yield session

DB = Annotated[AsyncSession, Depends(get_db)]

I tried every lazy loading option because that's commonly the issue. There is no resource I can find online that demonstrates how to build such a thing. No solution on Stackoverflow is found and ChatGPT just spits out a mess.

Did you try adding proper relationship definitions on your link table as well? (and provide a lazy loading strategy that means that everything gets fetched when the first request is made). The SQLModel examples uses that https://sqlmodel.tiangolo.com/tutorial/many-to-many/link-with-extra-fields/#update-link-model - but to get back to the core issue - I'm not sure if I'd actually make following and followers relationship properties on the User object when you're doing stuff async, since that means loading every follower ever time you need a user of any sort.

The query and read load on the database will scale rather badly in that case, meaning that you'll spend a lot more time reading and every query will explode in size as the number of followers increase.

What does the CurrentUser dependency look like? There might be some attempts at lazy loading in there. Also, could you add the full traceback, not just the error message?

This question is similar to: How to get user following/follows working with SQLModel/FastAPI. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
